# How to change the line-width of a React Icon?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I looked around for a simple solution to this, but couldn't find anything that worked. I'm trying to decrease the line-width of these React SVG icons for my input form, and make the icons thinner. Is this possible?

I tried using CSS stroke and stroke-width property, but it didn't work.

[image: My React Form]

Comment: If you could share code of any of your SVG icon, I will have a look at it and make it work. Share on codepen or jsfiddle. :)

Comment: Your question shows research effort. I have rated it :) Enjoy and Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If you are directly using SVG code as React Components. You will need to use the `stroke-width` property directly in each of your SVG code at the top level where `height, width and fill` properties are set.

Try this:

```
stroke-width="1"
```

2. If you are using React-Icons you can directly set a className on them and apply your CSS in your CSS file.

For Example:

```
import { FaBars } from "react-icons/fa";
```

Then while using set and apply your CSS.

```
<FaBars className="fa-bars" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using the react-icons library, and giving the icons their respective CSS classes. I am able to increase the height, width, set the color, etc, but I was just wondering if I am able to change the width/boldness of the lines in CSS.

Comment: While we can directly increase the width by doing .fa-bars path{ stroke-width: 67px; } but so far decreasing the width that the initial width isn't working. Will see the fix for that very soon Insha Allah. Do kindly accept the answer by clicking on tick icon and rate if my answer has helped you, so that other developers can also benefit from your question. Thank You :)